# How to weld two control points of a curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

Is it possible to weld or merge two control points of a curve?

Comment: How is this "weld/merge" different than deleting one of the two control points?

Comment: I think he means something like the *Remove Doubles* from mesh, to eliminate overlapping vertex

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not.

If it is a *Poly* type curve composed exclusively of straight linear segments, then you can safely convert it to a mesh object, remove doubles as mesh, then convert back to a curve.

If there are curved segments converting to mesh will be a destructive process, so the only way is to manually go over the duplicate vertex, and erase/fill.

Make sure you place the cursor over the existing handle first, so when you erase one vertex you can fix the handle position for the following one, then erase the vertex and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the gap or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to close the curve if it is the last gap. Then you can send the handle to the correct position using the snap menu with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*.

[image]

For Blender 2.8+ to make a spline cyclic or closed, select the spline and go to the menu at the top *Curve > Toggle Cyclic*.

You can also toggle it from the Properties Window > Curve Object Data > Active Spline > Cyclic U*.

[image]

Alternatively you can use [Lichtso's Curve CAD Blender addon](https://github.com/Lichtso/curve_cad), which among other features has a builtin [Merge Ends feature](https://github.com/Lichtso/curve_cad#merge-ends) for Bezier curves, vaguely similar to *Remove Doubles* for meshes.

> Merge Ends
>
> Merges two end control points into one while preserving the relative
> positions of their handles.

After installing and activating the addon in *User Preferences*, you can access the functionality while in *Edit Mode* in a Bezier curve object, by pressing <kbd>W</kbd> > *Specials Menu > Bezier CAD > Merge Ends*

For Blender 2.8+ *Add Curve: Curve Tools* addon is shipped by default and has a *Remove Doubles* operator that works like the mesh counterpart.

You can find it by default under the *3D View Sidebar* ( <kbd>N</kbd>, *Edit Tab*, *Sanitize > Remove Doubles*.

[image]

Comment: That was a brilliant solution! Thank you, Duarte!

Comment: @RobinBetts indeed good catch, I think it changed names at some point. Updated the name in the answer. Thanks