# Array modifier and merge distance for curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]

[image]

I want to do some knitting on cloth mesh and need to array knit curve,connect points and finally add bevel depth.But there is no merge by distance for curve and array modifier can't apply to curve.
What should I do ?

Comment: Hello :). The Array modifier has a built in. *Merge* option. Or you can use the Weld modifier.

Comment: @JachymMichal these modifiers are constructive,they can't be applied on curves.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm not sure it's at all possible: [How to weld two control points of a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86539/how-to-weld-two-control-points-of-a-curve)