# Is it possible to merge the ends of a path

Tags: path, curve-modifier

I am trying to create a racetrack in blender using my city, as long as there are no intersections i am doing fine. However i have no idea how to connect loose ends with the main track, snapping did not do the job, because i need to lay an array of roadpeaces on the curve and for some reason it does not work with snapping. Pls help me out on this one, if you have an idea.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86539/how-to-weld-two-control-points-of-a-curve https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/is-it-possible-to-extrude-a-curve-in-two-directions/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the curve type to **Cyclic**.

[image]

Comment: What is the keybinding to connect the two selected dots?

Comment: The shortcut is F. List of [shortcuts](https://www.makeuseof.com/blender-3-keyboard-shortcuts/).